# How to add multiple target columns in google sheets script when wanting to add a date to certain column

Tags: google-sheets

I have columns B-E where information will be entered and column A to add the date/timestamp for when all information in columns B-E has been entered. I have got it coded where if just column B is entered but am struggling to get it for when columns B-E are entered and not just column B.
I would also like the date and time format to be MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS:AM/PM

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var targetColumn = 2;
  
  if(targetColumn  && row >1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "HHAM"){
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).setValue(new Date());
}
}
```

Here is the document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KDywZKPUpbPImnnN-X9GeVLL_VUzu16vTwEGXwCHKQ0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Regex** to check if the edited cell belongs to columns B,C,D and E.

**Try this:**

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var range = e.range.getA1Notation();
  if(range.match(/[B,C,D,E]\d/) && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "HHAM"){
    var data = e.range.getValues();
    var filtered = data.filter(e => {
      return e[0] != ''
    });
    if(filtered.length == 0){
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).setValue(""); // this will remove the date to any deletion happen to cells
    }else{
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Data:

**Edit/Insert to a single cell:**

[image]

**Edit/Insert multiple data at once:**

[image]

To change the format to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS:AM/PM:

1. Highlight **column A**
2. Click **Format Tab -> Number -> More Formats -> Custom number format**
3. Paste this string: `mm"/"dd"/"yyyy" "hh":"mm":"ss" "AM/PM`

### References:

- [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Thank you! What can I add to the script so that if information is deleted from those cells, the date will be deleted as well and won't just add the date when the information was deleted?